# how to set a map like that "Map<String, bool>"

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, casting, boolean

I'm trying to set a `Map` as below but I get this error message

> "A value of type `'Set<Object>'` can't be assigned to a variable of type `'Map<String, bool>'`.
>   Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to `'Map<String, bool>'`."

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, bool>  _filters= {
    'gluten', false,
    'lactose', false,
    'vegan', false,
    'vegetarian', false,
  } ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a `Set` instead of `Map`. Try this instead (it is `:` for `Map`):

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, bool> _filters = {
    'gluten': false,
    'lactose': false,
    'vegan': false,
    'vegetarian': false,
  };
}
```